# Realm Object Server with watchOS

Tags: realm, watchkit, watchconnectivity, watchos-3

Is there a way to set up a synced realm on **watchOS**?

In order to do this, I believe you need a SyncUser object. I am currently trying to pass this object to the watch from the phone through `watchConnectivity`, but am not able to due to SyncUser not complying to `NSCoding`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you're asking is actually how to share a `SyncUser` object across devices. One way to do this would be to send the same information used to create the `Credential` (username/password, Facebook token, etc.) and authenticate again from the watch.